# Ajax with map, getting data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dictionary, jsonp

I'm trying to use the $.map in ajax and I don't success with getting the data from json array. I'll show you the json file, the ajax code and the json output i get. Hope you can help me, thank you very much :) and sorry for my english! Here is the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                  url: 'searchapi.php',
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                  },
                  success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map(data.table, function( item ) { //dont get this line!
                      return {
                        label: item.trid,
                        value: item.trid
                      }
                    }));
                  }
                });
```

And here is the json file:

```
 <?php 
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";
  $databaseName = "mydb";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

$data = ("select * from table;");

$json = array();
$result = mysql_query($data);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))     
{
$array = array(
    'trid' => $row['name'],
);
array_push($json, $array);
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;

die();

?>
```

Here is the json output:

```
 [{"name":"Emma"},{"name":"Eric"},{"name":"Peter"},{"name":"Sam"},{"name":"Roger"},{"name":"Sven"},{"name":"Julia"}]
```

Comment: where do you see this json output?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the wrong key, try it like this

```
$.map(data, function( item ) { //dont get this line!
                  return {
                    label: item.name,
                    value: item.name
                  }
                })
```